# Virtual Classes Segmentation Faults

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault, virtual-functions

I'm working on a graphic application. It makes significant use of virtual classes. I'm getting some segmentation faults that I'm having trouble debugging.

The primary classes in this application are:

- Shape (a virtual class)

  - Rectangle
  - Polygon
  - Circle
- Picture (essentially a collection of shapes)

Here is a shortened copy of the applicable part of my code:

```
class Picture
{
  ...
  Picture(Graphics& gd)
  {
    gfx = &gd;
  }

  void Picture::draw() const
  {
    for(int i=0; i<shapes.size();i++)
    {
      shapes[i]->draw(*gfx);  // This line causes a segmentation fault
    }
  }
...
private:
  std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
  Graphics* gfx;
}

class Shape
{
...
virtual void draw(Graphics& g) const = 0;
...
}
```

Here is a gdb session showing some information:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
[New process 89330    ]
#0  0x00020d38 in Rectangle::draw (this=0x41e10, g=@0xffbff904)
    at rectangle.cpp:42
42           g.setColor(getFillColor());
(gdb) print &g
$1 = (class Graphics *) 0xffbff904
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00020d38 in Rectangle::draw (this=0x41e10, g=@0xffbff904)
    at rectangle.cpp:42
#1  0x0001bae8 in Picture::draw (this=0xffbff950) at picture.cpp:45
#2  0x0002394c in writePicture (p=
      { = {_vptr.Figure = 0x2be38}, shapes = { >> = {_M_impl = {> = {> = {}, }, _M_start = 0x3f648, _M_finish = 0x3f664, _M_end_of_storage = 0x3f664}}, }, gfx = 0xffbff904}, fileName=
        {static npos = 4294967295, _M_dataplus = {> = {> = {}, }, _M_p = 0x3f49c "t1.dat.eps"}}) at testpicture.cpp:51
#3  0x00023b3c in simpleTest (inFileName=
        {static npos = 4294967295, _M_dataplus = {> = {> = {}, }, _M_p = 0x3fe24 "t1.dat"}}, outFileName=
        {static npos = 4294967295, _M_dataplus = {> = {> = {}, }, _M_p = 0x3f49c "t1.dat.eps"}}, bb=@0xffbff9c8) at testpicture.cpp:70
#4  0x00024c3c in main (argc=2, argv=0xffbffa74) at testpicture.cpp:165
```

I've been banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours now trying to figure this thing out. It has something to do with the Graphic member of the Picture class. However, I'm failing to see how it pieces together to create a segmentation fault.

EDIT:

Here is the portion of the testpicture.cpp where the Graphics object is created:

```
RectangularArea getPictureBounds (string fileName)
{
  ifstream in (fileName.c_str());

  PSGraphics gr(fileName + ".bb");
  Picture p0(gr);

  Shape* shape;
  while (in >> shape)
  {
    if (shape != NULL)
      p0.add(*shape);
  }
  return p0.boundingBox();
}
```

Graphic is a virtual class as well. In this case, PSGraphic inherits from it.

Comment: Can you post the `testpicture.cpp` - looks like the problem is there. How is the `Graphics` instance allocated?

Comment: One can tell by the address that it is allocated from stack (auto storage).

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. Questions hopefully make OP look at other parts of the code with suspicion.

Comment: I've added the testpicture.cpp code where the graphics object is created. 

If this object is on the stack, how can I put a copy of it on the heap? There is no clone function (I cannot add a clone function). If using a standard copy, the relevant data would be stripped since Graphic is virtual.

Comment: The `in >> shape` looks really suspicious here - most probably it just reads some integer into the pointer, and not allocate a `Shape` subclass as you expect.

Comment: @the_gastropod: the simplistic solution is to use `Picture p0(new PSGraphics(filename + ".bb"))`. However, you'll need to do something about the memory leak, such as using smart pointers.

Comment: @Nikolai: there isn't a standard extraction operator that will take a `Shape *`, correct? `operator>>(istream&, void*)` shouldn't work. The only way the code should compile is if the OP wrote the appropriate operator. Not to denigrate your comment--it's a very important point, but I'd downgrade from "really suspicious" to "somewhat suspicious".

Answer (score 2):

gfx points to an object in stack. Are you sure that the object is still there (at the same position where it was) when you are trying to draw?

Comment: This is a good point. How can I put this object on the heap since there's no clone() function available?

Comment: Allocate it by operator new, or put it inside some object that is allocated from heap.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice to store pointer to argument given to you as a reference - this creates confusion about memory **ownership**. Either make a copy of the referenced object (if it's a *value* class), or change the method to take **smart pointer** (like `boost::shared_ptr`) to the shared resource. This way the resource ownership management is explicit.

To your immediate issue - the `Graphics` instance is probably allocated on the stack and goes out of scope, thus destructed. Then your `Picture` code references dead object.